# Installed Ubuntu on Alienware m17xR4 but unable choice it at startup

Tags: boot, startup

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using a pen drive on Alienware m17xr4. But the problem is it doesn't shows up at start up but when I tried to install it once again using the pen drive it revealed the previous previous installation.

Answer (score 1):

Boot using a live usb/cd of ubuntu. 
Use `boot-repair` to fix the problem.

After booting with live usb/cd ,Run following command in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use `Recomended Repair`

More information can be found here- > https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

After running this program, it will show one url. Keep it with you. If the above method fails post that url here.